# How to get an attribute of a function without calling the function

Tags: python, python-2.7, attr

Say I have a function like so

```
def spam():
    spam.eggs = "Foobar"
    #do stuff
    return
```

I want to get the value of `spam.eggs` (`"Foobar"`) in another function without having to actually call the `spam()` method, for example,

```
def main():
  print spam.eggs
```

and I want it to return `Foobar`. However, obviously, this wouldn't work, since I haven't called spam() yet, so I've never assigned the `spam.eggs` property, so I'd have to do this

```
def main():
    spam()
    print spam.eggs
```

However, I don't want to call the `spam()` function if I want the `eggs` attribute, in fact, I want to check whether `spam()` has the eggs attribute, and if it equals `"Foobar"` before calling it, for example

```
def main():
    if hasattr(spam,'eggs'):
        if getattr(spam, 'eggs') == "Foobar":
            spam()
```

But like before, since I haven't called `spam` I haven't assigned `spam.eggs` yet.

Is there any way to do this, perhaps with a decorator? I want to keep the assignment somewhat close to the function, so I'd prefer something that's not like

```
def func():
    setattr(spam, 'eggs', 'Foobar')
```

Where I have to do `setattr()` in another method, unless in a decorator.

Comment: This is all a little too abstract for me.  (I'm assuming that I'm not the only person thinking "Why would you want to do that?").  Perhaps if you could tell us what you're attempting to actually do we might be able to suggest a more elegant alternative ... If not, it's always a little more motivating to know you're working on a real problem.

Comment: I have a module, with functions, that I'm trying to dynamically register with xmlrpc, like `server.register_function(function,function.attr)`, where the attribute is the RPC method name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be done with a decorator, yes:

```
def addEggs(func):
    func.eggs = "foobar"
    return func

@addEggs
def spam():
    pass

>>> spam.eggs
'foobar'
```

If you want to be able to specify the attribute name and/or value in a parameterized way, you'd have to write a more complex decorator:

```
def addAttr(attr, value):
    def deco(func):
        setattr(func, attr, value)
        return func
    return deco

@addAttr('attrName', 'value')
def spam():
    pass

>>> spam.attrName
'value'
```

However, there's still the question of why you want to do this.  If function attributes are useful at all, it's usually because there's a natural place to set them ---  that is, something else sets attributes on functions for its own purposes.  If you're just setting the attribute right when you define the function --- that is, if the attributes are an intrinsic part of the function itself --- it seems like you might want something more like a class with a method.

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- Yep, and this is a true decorator (rather than traditional decorators which I tend to think of more as transformations).  But the question is still "why?".  You could do `def spam():pass; spam.eggs = 'foobar'`

Comment: I like this solution better than `def spam():pass; spam.eggs = 'foobar'`, because it looks much nicer, and also gives me more control, even if it doesn't seem very "pythonic", though, I didn't know you could set attributes just right outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually want a class with static fields.  since variables are local to the function they are declared in there is no way to access them the way you want to

```
class Spam:
     eggs="foobar"
     def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         # do some stuff
         Spam.eggs = "foobared"

print Spam.eggs
Spam()
print Spam.eggs
```

Comment: What I want is to check whether a function has a certain attribute, if it matches, and if so, call it, rather than create a class.

Answer (score 1):

You would get the attribute with spam.eggs plain and simple. Btw you don't have to be inside the function to assign the attribute. You could do

```
def spam():
    #do stuff
    return
spam.eggs = "Foobar"
```

and then spam.eggs and spam() would work exactly the same